# How to get the current user in HTML?

Tags: html, xsjs

I have **user.xsjs** file which has the following code

```
var name1 = $.response.setBody($.session.getUsername());
```

I have **test.html** file I want to get the current user from **user.xsjs** file or aforesaid code directly used in **test.html** file to the get current user.

Need to get `"Welcome CurrentUser!"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `<script>` tag in which you can make an `ajax` call to user.xsjs file and then output response to HTML.

Comment: function getUsername() {
    var username = $.session.getUsername();
    return username;
}
var appuser = getUsername();